# Unlock the next cell when previous cell is filled

Tags: excel, vba, cell-formatting

**Situation**
I have an excel form and I want to ensure that the user go in a sequence where the next cell will be unlocked only if initial cells are filled up. My excel sheet also has some checkboxes as well as cell merged together.

**current solution**
I am using for example following code:-

```
If Range("V12").Value > 3 Or Range("V12").Value < 3 Then
    Me.Unprotect
    Range("E13:G17").Value = ""
     Range("E13:G17").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    Range("E13:G17").Locked = True
    Me.Protect
Else
    Me.Unprotect
    Range("E13:G17").Locked = False
    Range("E13:G17").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Me.Protect
```

but the problem is, I have multiple ranges and I have to write a repeated formula for the remaining ranges.

**My requirement**
Is this the optimal code or I can still improve my code? and I want user to jump only in the green field.

Please find the file through this link:-
[Link to the excel file,please click here](https://c.gmx.net/@944379538308077640/xZA117-MR22jxavoKDIJcQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of repeated code which could be reduced significantly if you factor out the Protect/Unprotect into a separate Sub.

Eg:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '...
    '...
    ProtectRange Me.Range("E13:G17"), (Me.Range("V12").Value > 3 Or _
                                       Me.Range("V12").Value < 3)
    
    ProtectRange Me.Range("L13:N17"), (Me.Range("V14").Value > 4 Or _
                                       Me.Range("V14").Value < 4)
    '...
    '...

End Sub

'Protect/unprotect range `rng` based on boolean `DoLock` (defaults to True)
Sub ProtectRange(rng As Range, Optional DoLock As Boolean = True)
    Me.Unprotect
    If DoLock Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'don't re-trigger event handler...
        rng.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    rng.Interior.Color = IIf(DoLock, RGB(226, 239, 218), RGB(255, 255, 255))
    rng.Locked = DoLock
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

Would also improve your code to check for a change in (eg) V12 before calling the lock/unlock sub, rather than processing every range regardless of where the Change event was triggered.

EDIT - another approach which should be faster when executing -

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim colLock As Collection    'any ranges to be locked
Dim colUnlock As Collection  'any ranges to be unlocked

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set colLock = New Collection    'reset collections
    Set colUnlock = New Collection

    'Test each section in turn and decide if to lock/unlock...

    CheckRange Me.Range("V12"), Target, Me.Range("E13:G17"), _
              (Me.Range("V12").Value > 3 Or Me.Range("V12").Value < 3)
    
    CheckRange Me.Range("V14"), Target, Me.Range("L13:N17"), _
              (Me.Range("V14").Value > 4 Or Me.Range("V14").Value < 4)
    
    
    'check more ranges.....
    
    'Done testing: anything to lock/unlock ?
    If colLock.Count > 0 Or colUnlock.Count > 0 Then
        Me.Unprotect
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        'loop over any collected ranges
        For Each rng In colLock
            rng.ClearContents
            rng.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
            rng.Locked = True
        Next rng
        For Each rng In colUnlock
            rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            rng.Locked = False
        Next rng
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Me.Protect
    End If
End Sub

'Check if `Target` includes `rngTrigger`, and if it does then collect `rngLock` in
'  either `ColLock` or `colUnlock` depending on the test result in `doLock`
Sub CheckRange(rngTrigger As Range, Target As Range, rngLock As Range, doLock As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(rngTrigger, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If doLock Then
            Debug.Print "Locking " & rngLock.Address()
            colLock.Add rngLock
        Else
            Debug.Print "Unlocking " & rngLock.Address()
            colUnlock.Add rngLock
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams. I applied the above code, it works fine. I have the codes in the worksheet and not as module especially for "Protect/unprotect range `rng` based on boolean `DoLock` (defaults to True)". One mor thing, I noticed my excel file is little slower, maybe the code runs in background too muc?

Comment: That's what I meant about restricting what runs based on what cell(s) have been changed - for example only switch the state for E13:G17 if Target contains V12.

Comment: Hi @Tim, 
the alternative approach that would be faster when executing unfortunately does not trigger. I tried to check it out but no success. I am not a professional though and therefore learning with practical use.

Comment: Helloo,
i have one more new requirement, I am trying to use above range using multiple cases. I have three cases (actiavted using checkbox) through which I will activate different set of ranges and values, Is it possible in this example?

Comment: You're monitoring both calculated and manual-entry ranges, so that makes it more difficult - there's no Target to check when responding to the calculation event.  If you drop your email here I will send you a copy of your file with some changes which worked for me (but the whole thing is too complex for me to review)

Comment: I sent you a mail - you can remove your email address...